# Do Giant Creatures have any RAW way of physically attacking in an area of effect pattern?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack, area-of-effect

Are there any significantly large creatures that can **physically** attack in an area of effect pattern? (not looking for breath or spells) Say a giant swings a sword in a wide arc, and attacks in a 15ft cone or something along that line.  The closest thing I can think of would be something like Cleave. Is there any other ways this style of attack can be backed up with feats or monsters with similar abilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that the [Cleave](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/great-cleave-combat-final) line of feats can be used to make attack patterns similar to what you describe. But the ability to attack in a certain area is traditionally in the hands of spellcasters.

However, there are other ways to also obtain similar effects:

- [Cleaving Sweep](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cleaving-sweep-combat/) feat will allow you to make a trip attack on all threatened targets on a full attack.
- [Sweeping Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/champion/champion-path-abilities/sweeping-strike-su/) Mythic Champion 6th tier ability will allow you to make an attack on all adjacent enemies instead of your normal full attack.
- [Whirlwind Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/whirlwind-attack-combat-final/) will allow you to make one melee attack against all enemies within reach.

Certain [firearms](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/firearms/) can also attack in an area, due to the **Scatter** weapon quality. Several [technological weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/technological-weapons/) can also physically hit targets in an area, but those are mostly duplicating spell effects (like [rocket launchers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/technological-weapons#TOC-Rocket-Launcher)). So we will see [technological-themed creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/robot/robot-annhiliator/) that can also attack in an area using similar special abilities.

There are also (few) specific creatures that can make physical attacks in an area, like a [Dragon's Tail Sweep](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon#tail-sweep) attack, that can hit everyone in a 30 ft half circle area near the creature. Some dragons also have the [Crush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/) special ability, which allows them to use their body to attack all creatures within their occupied area.

Swarms and [troops](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/troop/) can physically attack anyone inside the area they occupy, similar to creatures with [Engulf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/gelatinous-cube/). Similar to these creatures, the [Whirlwind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#Whirlwind_Su) special ability also allows certain creatures (like [elementals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-air/huge-air-elemental)) to make slam attacks on all creatures inside their whirlwind radius.

There are other creatures, but the abilities that allow them to physically attack in an area are specific to those creatures, not some generic ability that all similar creatures would share, or that we would expect them to share (like the [Kaiju](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/kaiju/)).

Comment: Dragons's Tail Sweep attack seems to set a precedent. At least enough for me to flavor it to other creatures. Thanks.

Comment: You can also spread iterative attacks out across targets in a 'sweep' and flavor it as one wide attack.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, there is

[Great Old One, Cthulhu](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/great-old-ones/great-old-one-cthulhu/)'s Cleaving Claws:

> A single attack from one of Cthulhu’s claws can target all creatures in a 10-foot square. Make one attack roll; any creature in the area whose AC is equal to or lower than the result takes damage from the claw.

I thought the [Kaijus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/kaiju/) would have similar abilities, but strangely they don't.

Comment: @ShadowKras: it is a direct answer to the question: "Are there any significantly large creatures that can physically attack in an area of effect pattern?" "Yes, here is an example."